# Fragment with buttons: onClick() vs. XML onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a rather simple screen that only has 4 buttons. I'm implementing it as a Fragment like so:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
   // ...

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {}
}
```

Each button already has `onClick` specified to a function in the Activity that the Fragment is attached. The issue I'm having is that the `onClick` functions aren't called when the buttons are clicked. I've left `MainFragment.onClick()` empty - but is that the right approach? Does it need to be implemented for the functions to be invoked? If so, the `onClick` attributes in the Button layouts would seem redundant.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The `onClick` in the XML will only ever call methods in the `Activity`, not in the `Fragment`. Often this isn't very useful. What you're doing is ok, you don't need the XML `onClick` attribute. You can use a callback to communicate with your `Activity` if necessary, but you don't have to. If you can handle the button click in the `Fragment` alone, that's fine too.

Comment: If you leave it empty it will do nothing of course. If you need to communicate with the `Activity`, do what @meda says. Whether you have to communicate with the `Activity` or not I can't tell you, that depends what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I never use the `xml` `onClick` attributes. Although they may save a couple of lines of typing, they make it more difficult to follow what's happening in your code.

If your class `implements` `View.OnClickListener` and you have correctly overriden the `onClick` method (which it looks like you have), then you can safely remove any `onClick`s in your `layout` files and instead assign methods to your widget clicks in the following way:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button viewOne, viewTwo, viewThree;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

        viewOne = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_one);
        viewTwo = //etc...

        //"this" refers to the current object. As the object is of a class that implements OnClickListener, 
        //passing "this" satisfies the View.OnClickListener parameter required for the setOnClickListener() method.
        viewOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewThree.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }


   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       //To identify the correct widget, use the getId() method on the view argument
       int id = view.getId();
       switch (id) {
           case R.id.view_one:
               //viewOne clicked
               break;
           case R.id.view_two:
               //And so on...
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The right approach is to use a fragment listener to communicate back with the activity:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements MainFragment.onFragmentInteraction{
    ...

    public void onFragmentInteraction() {
        // Do something 
        callFunction();
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment:

```
mYourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does that mean the XML `onClick` attribute shouldn't be used?

Comment: I dont know maybe it will work, but I never do this, I prefer it in my code

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `onClick` in your XML, the click events will go to your container Activity. But you can have the click events go directly to your Fragment by setting the `onClickListener` to your Fragment's implementation of it. So in your Fragment's `onCreateView()` method, you would inflate your layout, then set the Button's `onClickListener` to your Fragment's implementation like this...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

By setting the `setOnClickListener()` to `this`, you are sending all click events for that button to your Fragment instead of your Activity. Then you would just handle your `onClick` events as you're already doing...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("YOUR BUTTON", "This is called from your Fragment instead of your Activity");
}
```